# Как найти строки, которые заканчиваются на ".doc"?

Tags: sql, mariadb

Нужно найти строки, которые заканчиваются на ".doc".

Что-то такое:

```
SELECT `name` FROM `portal`.`files` WHERE `name` LIKE `*.doc`;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT name FROM portal.files WHERE name LIKE '%.doc';
```

или

```
SELECT name FROM portal.files WHERE RIGHT(name, 4) = '.doc';
```

или

```
SELECT name FROM portal.files WHERE name REGEXP '\.doc$';
```

или (для MariaDB версии 10.0.11+):

```
SELECT name FROM portal.files WHERE name RLIKE '\.doc$';
```